# Arrayformula count cells containing partial text and sum for multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, count, array-formulas

I have found formulas that count vertically in google sheets, I would like to count horizontally.

In column A i have users.

I then want to count their multiple choice answers that are answered in the next columns but all contained within a single row. The only issue is some questions contain multiple answers so I need to select for partial text as well.

I wish to also have this operate as an arrayformula for when new users complete the quiz without having to copy the formula

How would I get separate counts on for A B C D columns at the end of the answered columns for the same row?

for example:

| Name | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 | Question 4 | Count#A | Count#B | Count#C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | A | AB | A | C | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| User 2 | B | AC | B | CA | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| User 3 | C | AA | B | CC | 2 | 1 | 3 |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share a link to a spreadsheet with the above information already manually typed into it (including Column I with header Count#D). Please indicated whether the possible entries in Columns B:F are literally A, B, C and D or whether those are just placeholders, and if placeholders, enter into your sample spreadsheet realistic/actual possibilities that may appear in those columns. Include three user rows as shown. Be sure to set the link's Share permissions (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Also, please indicate whether there will always be exactly four Question columns, or whether there might be more; and how the raw data in Columns A:E is getting into the sheet that will contain the results from Columns F:I (e.g., manually entered, form, formulas referencing form intake sheet, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following formulas in cells

Count#A

> ={"Count#A";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"",LEN({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E})-LEN(SUBSTITUTE({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E},"A","")),))}
> [image]

Count#B

> ={"Count#B";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"",LEN({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E})-LEN(SUBSTITUTE({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E},"B","")),))}
> [image]

Count#C

> ={"Count#C";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A<>"",LEN({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E})-LEN(SUBSTITUTE({B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E},"C","")),))}
> [image]

and remove all the content from the range below these cells
[image]

Comment: Perfection. Thank you

Comment: It's my pleasure